# Lottie animation not showing in ScrollView React Native

Tags: react-native, lottie

I have a Lottie animation which works when I put it in a `View`:

```
return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }} >
            <LottieView
             source={require('../../src/629-empty-box.json')}
             loop
             autoPlay
             style={{ scaleX: 1.4, scaleY: 1.4 }}
             />
     </View>
)
```

but does not work when I change `View` to `ScrollView`:

```
 return (
    <ScrollView>
          <LottieView
           source={require('../../src/629-empty-box.json')}
           loop
           autoPlay
           style={{ scaleX: 1.4, scaleY: 1.4 }}
           />
    </ScrollView>
)
```

There is just a blank screen but however I get this error (error also present when I put it in `View`):

```
'scaleX' supplied to 'LottieView' has been deprecated. Use the transform prop instead.
```

I'm rendering the animation in a functional component and need the animation in a `ScrollView` for `refreshControl`.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding height and width for lottieview

Comment: @GvsAkhil Thanks for replying, but adding height and width did not help. Adding height and width makes it disappear in both `View` and `ScrollView`